# Open a list when clicked on a image with rotate image

Tags: javascript, css

Have the following structure: Need to open the list upwards on top of the image when clicked on the image and **rotate the image to 180 deg** with some linear transition effect,

```
<div class="wrapper">
     <span><Image></span>
    <ul class="list">
    <li class="">
     <a href="">item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
     <a href="">item 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
     <a href="">item 3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
     <a href="">item 4</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

tried with sibling max-height, but not getting the effect I wanted

```
list{
 max-height: 0;
 overflow:hidden;
}
a:focus+list{
 max-height:10rem;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you are:

```css
.list {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

span {outline:0}

span img {transition:.5s}

span:focus img {transform: rotate(90deg)}

span:focus+.list {
  max-height: 10rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span tabindex="1">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100">
  </span>
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="">
      <a href="">item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
      <a href="">item 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
      <a href="">item 3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
      <a href="">item 4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/5724303/kosh-very - this works well for the requirement, but I unfortunately have an issue where clicking on <a> triggers page refresh, is there any other way to get around this issue - btw I am using this in reactjs.

Comment: @monkeyjs, thank you, I've updated my answer. You might replace `<a>`with `<span>`.